# Facebook Cache won't flush?

Tags: facebook, caching, iframe

I just renamed my facebook application, but the Like button and the link sharer didn't change, even I used the debug tool (no more Linter tool ??). Any Idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to clear the facebook cache of your app/url.

you can do this on the facebook url linter. http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

insert the url which you are tring to like, and you will be presented with the info facebook see's. side effect is that its refreshes facebook cache from this url.

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug is not clearing the cache, I read somewhere that debug tool can't flush links with more than 100 connections

Comment: I tried it, no use. Debug tool won't flush cache.

Comment: yeah facebook changed a lot in the last 3 years. it seems right now it only works with https urls .. dont know why.

Comment: It should work for all URLs. You can do it programatically as well by making a post request to graph URL and pass URL as ID in data.

This might help http://alfanso.com/asking-facebook-to-clear-cached-data/